# How to exclude a test from appearing in the documentation

Tags: java, spring, testing, apiblueprint, dredd

I'm working with **Dredd** the **HTTP API Testing Framework** to test my backend apis. 
Well the idea is that each time you create a test case a documentation will be generated automatically which is a good practice to ensure that documentation is always up to date and test driven.
Sometimes I want to create a test case **without generating its relative documentation**. I would like to find a way how to **exclude** a **test case** from appearing into the **documentation**.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple API description documents. One will be user-facing, with documentation, and another one can be with corner cases useful just for testing. Dredd can accept multiple documents using the [--path](https://dredd.org/en/latest/usage-cli.html#cmdoption-path) option.

One other thing is you could compose the document from multiple ones. You didn't mention which API description format you're using, so I can't give you a direct example. In case of [API Blueprint](http://apiblueprint.org/), you could use [Hercule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hercule).